# Xamarin.Forms.Map Pin.Clicked not working

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to run a method when I click on my pins. I believe I am doing everything right, but the event is just not triggering. There are some similar questions from 2015, but they all point to a bug in Xamarin.Forms that should have been fixed long time ago. My NuGet manager for solution says my Xamarin.Forms is much newer than the faulty version.

Here is my code:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        await InitializeMapAsync();
    }


    public async Task InitializeMapAsync()
    {
        var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
        var userPosition = await locator.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
        var position = new Position(userPosition.Latitude, userPosition.Longitude);


        var map = new Map(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(position, Distance.FromKilometers(10)))
        {
            IsShowingUser = true,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand

        };

        var items = await WebHelper.GetItems(position.Latitude.ToString(), position.Longitude.ToString(), "user");
        if(items != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                var pin = new Pin()
                {
                    Label = item.Price,
                    Position = new Position(double.Parse(item.Lat), double.Parse(item.Lng))
                };
                pin.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
                {
                    var p = sender as Pin;
                    DisplayAlert("Clicked", "Clicked!", "ok");
                };
                map.Pins.Add(pin);
            }
        }

        var stack = new StackLayout { Spacing = 0 };
        stack.Children.Add(map);
        Content = stack;
    }
```

My pins are added to the map, but when I click on them, they are just showing a tooltip and not running my custom DisplayAlert method.

Is there any visible mistakes?

For the record, I am testing on an Android tablet.

Comment: Still looks like there is [some bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=40478)

Comment: Looks a bit unstable.. I guess I will try use a platform-specific way.

Comment: Hi @mathkid91. This thread is a bit old but if you still have this issue, you may want to add some comment to [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=40478)

Comment: Hi,
I eventually solved this by writing platform specific code. I can try find my code solution if someone wants it (its a bit old project now though), but its not the ideal crossplatform solution I like, its just a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Just one observation with the improper use of `async void` on `OnAppearing`, which is not an event handler.

```
protected override void OnAppearing() {
    this.Appearing += Page_Appearing;
}

public async void Page_Appearing(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.Appearing -= Page_Appearing;
    await InitializeMapAsync();
}
```